# C# getting the biggest area of a matrix which has the same element

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

In C# I've come to a problem I can't solve myself. I have a *2d matrix* which looks like this

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to find out the biggest **4-connected** (north, west, south, east) area of `0`. For the example above the answer is `8` (the biggest area of all zeroes is on the top of the matrix):

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

I have no idea how to cope such a task, so anything could help.

Thanks!

I've tried *iterating* through the matrix with a `for` but its not working if the biggest area where `0` are on the same line (or column).

Comment: Have look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74278474/recursion-stack-overflow-and-i-dont-understand-why/74278557#74278557
the only difference that there `1` instead of `0`

Comment: Check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/ it will help you. After this you only have to calculate the area of the resulting matrix

Answer (score 1):

You can scan the map and on each `0` perform a *search* (in the code below it is **B**readth **F**irst **S**earch):

**Code:** ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uKrHgW))

```
private static int MaxIsland(int[,] ocean) {
  int result = 0;

  if (ocean == null)
    return result;

  var visited = new HashSet<(int y, int x)>();

  for (int y = 0; y < ocean.GetLength(0); ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < ocean.GetLength(1); ++x) {
      if (ocean[y, x] != 0)
        continue;
      if (!visited.Add((y, x)))
        continue;

      int current = 1;
      var agenda = new Queue<(int y, int x)>();

      agenda.Enqueue((y, x));

      while (agenda.Count > 0) {
        var (r, c) = agenda.Dequeue();
 
        for (int d = 0; d < 4; ++d) {
          int newR = r + (d - 1) % 2;
          int newC = c + (d - 2) % 2;

          if (newC < 0 || newR < 0 || 
              newR >= ocean.GetLength(0) || newC >= ocean.GetLength(1))
            continue;
          if (ocean[newR, newC] != 0)
            continue;
          if (visited.Add((newR, newC))) {
            agenda.Enqueue((newR, newC));
            current += 1;
          }
        }
      }

      result = Math.Max(result, current);
    }

  return result;
}
```

Time complexity: `O(n * m)` where `n` and `m` are matrix dimensions

Space complexity: `O(n * m)` in the worst case